# Tracking changes from a certain point in time with EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

The EntityState property of an entity tracks the state of an EF entity, starting from the point in time when it was added to the DBContext.

What if I want to track changes from another point in time.

The situation that calls for this is:
On an edit form, I am trying to warn the user on exit about saving the entity if it is modified. This is not much of a problem for existing entities, since they are marked as Modified when something is changed. But for new entities, EntityState is always "Added" so I cannot track if anything is changed or not.

While creating a new entity, I run some initialization code. There is no need to warn the user if the new entity is created, initialized but not modified by the user. So I want to start change tracking just after init code runs. DBUpdates should work as before, needless to say.

How can I do that?

Note: There are some possible solutions I came up with. First is keeping the original copy of the entity and doing a field by field comparison when needed. Another is keeping a "modified" variable myself and writing many event handlers to editor controls for updating it. 
Both are expensive, hard to maintain and are not considered to be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it by keeping track of a "Modified" variable myself and setting it to true if anything changes.
The trick is, I am using PropertyChanged event of the entity so I didn't have to write separate event handlers for editor controls. And more, I attached the event handler AFTER initializing the entity so initial changes I make are ignored but only changes by user are tracked.

Answer (score 0):

You must code it yourselves. There is no way to stop change tracking for attached entity or revert only selected changes. You must make clone of your entity and synchronize changes manually if user confirm changes.

> Both are expensive, hard to maintain and are not considered to be an option.

If you modify only single entity (not its relation), EF will provide you single method to apply new values (DbContext API):

```
context.Entry(attachedEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(modifiedClone);
```

If you modify entity graph (more related entities) you must indeed do it manually.

Edit:

It is the same in case of EFv4 with ObjectContext API and you can use this helper:

```
context.YourEntitySet.ApplyCurrentValues(modifiedClone);
```

Comment: I got my projects mixed. Sorry. I am using EF4 and ModelFirst. Code-First was some other project. My bad ... very sorry. I updated tags.

Comment: Having said that, Is that Entry method part of EF 4.1? I cannot find it on DBContext object? If that method (or some other) also allows changing Original values with a single method call, then I can set the entity as unmodified after initializing the entity. Let the user make his changes, check for changes and change original values with my clone object with a single line of code before save.